# OpenSSL on Windows: Problems by signing a file through commandline

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012, openssl, digital-signature

I have to sign an XML-File with OpenSSL on a Windows-Server 2012 through command-line.

Unfortunately it didn`t work out if I set the passphrase inside the command.
I then always get the error: "Can only sign or verify one file"

If I use commandline without the passphrase-option then it seems to work as it then questions for passphrase and if entered creates sig-file.

Unfortunately I would like to use the command in an automated script, so I need to pass the passphrase via commandline.

Tried with following lines:

Without passphrase-option (works fine):

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe dgst -sha512 -binary -out "D:\BZSt\CRS\m5_cs_bz101481661_1013801661_test00000001.xml.sig" -sign "D:\BZSt\CRS\SFTP-Keys\FinDK_elster_2048.pem" "D:\BZSt\CRS\m5_cs_bz101481661_1013801661_test00000001.xml"
```

With passphrase-option (Not working / Note: Password stored in txt-file as it contains special characters and escaping through double-quotes around password has not worked):

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe dgst -sha512 -binary -out "D:\BZSt\CRS\m5_cs_bz101481661_1013801661_test00000001.xml.sig" -sign "D:\BZSt\CRS\SFTP-Keys\FinDK_elster_2048.pem" "D:\BZSt\CRS\m5_cs_bz101481661_1013801661_test00000001.xml" -pass file:"D:\BZSt\CRS\SFTP-Keys\BZSt-Passphrase.txt"
```

Maybe I have wrong syntax anywhere.
Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

P. Baeumel

Answer (score 1):

Checking the man page for [openssl-dgst](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/dgst.html) (v1.0.2, but also valid for other less-recent versions) shows that the correct argument for a passphrase argument is **`-passin`**, not `-pass`.

Since the argument `-pass` is not recognised as an option switch, and the last parameter(s) of the dgst command indicate the filename, it is presuming you are providing three filenames: The file you are interested in, a file named `-pass` and a file named `file:D:\.....`, hence the error message you are receiving.